# What should be strategy to deal with ultra eager Apache Camel route?

Tags: routes, apache-camel

In my Camel Context, I have created 5 routes. Each of these routes listen to a designated folder.

**The Setup**

Route-A listens to a folder `/net` for input files. This folder location used from a client over SFTP who drops file in this location. Once a file is received in this location the route will read the file name and as per the name pattern, the file is moved to a location `/type_a/inbound`.

Route-B listens to `/type_a/inbound` for input files. When file is received in this location it will process this file as per its business logic.

All other routes work as same.

**Problem**

In today feed there is a file with large size(1.4GB).  When Route-A starts to copy this file at `/type_a/inbound`, before it is completed the Route-B starts to read from the file. This causes the error in the Route-B. This does not happen as the route configuration for Route-A has `?exclude=.*.filepart"` added in the endpoint. This `.filepart` file is not being created by Route-A at `/type_a/inbound`.

What options I do have to block the Route-B till the copy process is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `readLock` option for your route B file consumer endpoint - http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

> Used by consumer, to only poll the files if it has exclusive read-lock on the file (i.e. the file is not in-progress or being written). Camel will wait until the file lock is granted.

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, you can also use a done file. This way your large file is not polled until the 'done' file appears in the directory. Here is an example:

```
file:bar?doneFileName=${file:name}.done
```